# CI multiple file upload - cannot upload more than 2 files

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

This function cannot upload more than 2 images.  If tried produces error,

*Message : undefined index:userfile*

**View**
`<input name="userfile[]" id="userfile" type="file" multiple="" />`

**Controller**

```
 function do_upload() {

    $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);

    foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value){
        for($n=0; $n<=$count-1; $n++) {
            $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$n];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$n];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$n];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$n];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$n];   

                $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
                                    $config['max_size']       = 0;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $data = $this->upload->data();
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the number of files that is the problem?  Have you tried uploading several tiny files?  Could it be your max upload/post size settings in apache?

Comment: Can you post more of your view code?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, i didn't know, i was uploading 10mb photos. Solved

Comment: Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: No problem man...I had the same issue and it took me some time to figure out.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely look into your php.ini max post/upload size.  Look for values like:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = ##M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = ##M
```

and change the # to values that will suit you